# Xamarin Studio won't launch, but the ERRORS are apparently unique to me

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin-studio

So basically I wanted to follow Brackeys' C# course, but I wasn't able to continue past the first video because well... even though I've got gtk-sharp installed, and I already have Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5 AND 4.6 installed (for some reason), the damn thing just won't start. Screenshot of the last log, gotten after pressing "Run" on XamarinStudio.exe:

[image: Screenshot of the last log, gotten after pressing "Run" on XamarinStudio.exe]

I've been searching for hours on the internet and though I'm not the best at searching for stuff on the internet, it would seem reasonable to think I apparently am the only one dumb enough to get this problem and not understand how to fix it without using internet.

Therefore, I must rely on you, people of Stack Overflow ! All help is appreciated :)

Thanks in advance!

P.S (and it's a damn huge one):

In case the pic isn't high quality enough for you to distinguish words and letters, here's a copypaste of the log (sorry that some stuff in it is in french :/ ):

> INFO [2017-06-28 21:06:44Z]: Did not find previous version from which to migrate data
>
> INFO [2017-06-28 21:06:44Z]: Starting Xamarin Studio 6.1.2 (build 44)
>
> INFO [2017-06-28 21:06:44Z]: Running on Microsoft .NET 4.0.30319.42000
>
> INFO [2017-06-28 21:06:44Z]: Operating System: Windows 10.0.14393.0 (64-bit)
>
> INFO [2017-06-28 21:06:44Z]: Found GTK# version 2.12.44
>
> WARNING [2017-06-28 21:06:44Z]: Storage folder: C:\Users\Raphaël\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Cache\AppInsights\ad58ff9da41d9e46a009b5b523971c10f8ed4e28
>
> ERROR [2017-06-28 21:06:45Z]: PersistenceTransmitter: Unhandled exception in CreateSenders:
>
> INFO [2017-06-28 21:06:45Z]: Using GTK+ 2.24.26
>   System.InvalidOperationException: Extension node not found in path: /MonoDevelop/Core/WebCredentialProviders
>      à Mono.Addins.ExtensionContext.GetExtensionObjects[T](String path, Boolean reuseCachedInstance) dans C:\data\lanes\3510\0ccfcd52\source\monodevelop\main\external\mono-addins\Mono.Addins\Mono.Addins\ExtensionContext.cs:ligne 636
>      à Mono.Addins.ExtensionContext.GetExtensionObjects[T](String path) dans C:\data\lanes\3510\0ccfcd52\source\monodevelop\main\external\mono-addins\Mono.Addins\Mono.Addins\ExtensionContext.cs:ligne 607
>      à Mono.Addins.AddinManager.GetExtensionObjects[T](String path) dans C:\data\lanes\3510\0ccfcd52\source\monodevelop\main\external\mono-addins\Mono.Addins\Mono.Addins\AddinManager.cs:ligne 629
>      à MonoDevelop.Core.WebRequestHelper.Initialize() dans C:\data\lanes\3510\0ccfcd52\source\monodevelop\main\src\core\MonoDevelop.Core\MonoDevelop.Core\WebRequestHelper.cs:ligne 48
>      à MonoDevelop.Core.Runtime.Initialize(Boolean updateAddinRegistry) dans C:\data\lanes\3510\0ccfcd52\source\monodevelop\main\src\core\MonoDevelop.Core\MonoDevelop.Core\Runtime.cs:ligne 126
>
> INFO [2017-06-28 21:06:45Z]: GTK: Using Gtk theme from C:\Users\Raphaël\AppData\Roaming\XamarinStudio-6.0\Config\share\themes\Light
>   Démarrage de Xamarin Studio
>
> FATAL ERROR [2017-06-28 21:06:45Z]: Xamarin Studio failed to start. Some of the assemblies required to run Xamarin Studio (for example gtk-sharp)may not be properly installed in the GAC.
>   System.InvalidOperationException: Extension node not found in path: /MonoDevelop/Core/PlatformService
>      à Mono.Addins.ExtensionContext.GetExtensionObjects(String path, Type arrayElementType, Boolean reuseCachedInstance) dans C:\data\lanes\3510\0ccfcd52\source\monodevelop\main\external\mono-addins\Mono.Addins\Mono.Addins\ExtensionContext.cs:ligne 669
>      à Mono.Addins.AddinManager.GetExtensionObjects(String path) dans C:\data\lanes\3510\0ccfcd52\source\monodevelop\main\external\mono-addins\Mono.Addins\Mono.Addins\AddinManager.cs:ligne 553
>      à MonoDevelop.Ide.DesktopService.Initialize() dans C:\data\lanes\3510\0ccfcd52\source\monodevelop\main\src\core\MonoDevelop.Ide\MonoDevelop.Ide\DesktopService.cs:ligne 76
>      à MonoDevelop.Ide.IdeStartup.Run(MonoDevelopOptions options) dans C:\data\lanes\3510\0ccfcd52\source\monodevelop\main\src\core\MonoDevelop.Ide\MonoDevelop.Ide\IdeStartup.cs:ligne 169
>      à MonoDevelop.Ide.IdeStartup.Main(String[] args, IdeCustomizer customizer) dans C:\data\lanes\3510\0ccfcd52\source\monodevelop\main\src\core\MonoDevelop.Ide\MonoDevelop.Ide\IdeStartup.cs:ligne 594

Comment: Did you try googling? https://kb.xamarin.com/customer/portal/articles/1659181-xamarin-studio-fails-to-start-on-windows-due-to-security-settings

Comment: Xamarin Studio is also no longer being supported. On Windows you should be using VS2017 with the Xamarin workload